# Awaiting for services to return data or converting service into global dataset and passing it into angular controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have simple problem of needing to wait on certain data to return from service calls before executing logic that depends on the data in question.

As confusing as it sounds I have this extract controller that I am working on at the moment which is exhibiting that problem.

```
// async services: $stateParams, GetTags, GetStrands, GetLessons, GetPlan, UpdatePlan, SavePlan
myApp.controller('EditNewCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'GetTags', 'GetStrands', 'GetLessons', 'GetPlan', 'UpdatePlan', 'SavePlan', function ($scope, $stateParams, GetTags, GetStrands, GetLessons, GetPlan, UpdatePlan, SavePlan) {
    // $stateParams correspondent to two different routes for this controller
    // #/~/
    // #/~/:planId
    // #/~/:planId/:year/:level
    $scope.planId = $stateParams.planId; // only defined when editing a plan
    $scope.year = $stateParams.year; // may or may not be defined
    $scope.level = $stateParams.level; // may or may not be defined

    ...

    // calls to retrieve stuff from the server
    GetTags.get({ groupId: 12, }, function (data) {
        $scope.tags = data.tags; // go know when this will return
    });

    GetStrands.get({ groupId: 12, }, function (data) {
        $scope.strands = data.strands; // god knows when this will return
    });

    GetLessons.get({ groupId: 12, }, function (data) {
        $scope.lessons = data.lessons; // god know when this will return
    });

    // helpers
    ...

    // init select controls
    if ($scope.planId != undefined && $scope.planId > 0) {
        GetPlan.get({ planId: $scope.planId, groupId: 12, }, function (data) {
            var plan = data.plan; // god know when this will return

            plan.Year = $scope.getYearById(plan.Year); // convert int to object
            plan.Level = $scope.getLevelById(plan.Level); // convert in to object

            $scope.plan = plan;
        });
    } else {
        $scope.plan = { Name: '', Strand: {}, Year: {}, Level: {}, Tags: [], Lessons: [], };
    }

    if ($scope.year != undefined) {
        $scope.plan.Year = $scope.getYearObj($scope.year);
    }

    if ($scope.level != undefined) {
        $scope.plan.Level = $scope.getLevelObj($scope.level);
    }
}]);
```

More often then not I run into a problem with `$scope.plan.Year = $scope.getYearObj($scope.year);` and `$scope.plan.Level = $scope.getLevelObj($scope.level);` when I enter edit mode. While I understand that service call happens asynchronously but what is the common ways of slowing down subsequent calls? Or perhaps its better to just encapsulate problem loginc in `$scope.$watch`?

I have another concern with `$scope.tags` and `$scope.strands`. Is it possible to have these datasets pre-fetched and managed (when I say managed I mean refreshed every so often in the background) on a more global level and have them passed in as references instead rather than retrieving these in every controller that I come up with. Please advise if there is Angular structure or mechanism for something like this.

In any case it is clear to me that I am doing something wrong here. Please advice what is the best course of action or where I should look.

#### Complementary notes

Just to complement suggested solution to my dilemma.

Because I am not using the `$http` services but instead I use AngularJs [REST/factory services](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/docs/tutorial/step_11). Example of such service would look like so:

```
myApp.factory('GetTags', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/API/Service/GetTagList', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, }, isArray: true,
    });
}]);
```

How to use this in a controller is already shown above but sometimes that's not enough. This is how one would use this service in a situation when you need access to `then`:

```
.state('state', {
    url: '/url:Id',
    templateUrl: '/template.html',
    resolve: {
        Tags: function (GetTags) {
            //TODO: need to make a directive that returns groupId
            return GetTags.get({ groupId: 12, }).$promise.then(
                function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        return data.tags;
                    } else {
                        return [];
                    }
                });
        },
    },
    controller: 'EditNewCtrl',
})
```

Here `$promise` is used to [gain access to the raw `$http` promise object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) which allows us to use `.then()` to await for the call to resolve. Without `$promise` in other words just `return GetTags.get({ groupId: 12, })` would return the promise object to the controller in question which no good.

To gain access to for example `$stateParams.Id` just pass it into the function call like so:

```
Tags: function (GetTags, $stateParams) {
    return $stateParams.Id;
},
```

That's about it really. Just don't forget to pass in your resolved data objects/structures into your controller.

PS: Also important to note that definition for `controller` must come after definition for `resolve` otherwise it doesn't work.

PSS: I hope that advice that I have received and my example helps to complement the answers given.

Comment: You can use the resolve functionality of $state/$stateProvider (ui-router) to resolve data before entering a view and its viewmodel (controller). Furthermore, you can provide a callback mechanism to notify your controller all data is loaded.

Comment: @skubski you are correct I have noticed provided ``resolve functionality`` in ui-router docs - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve but is it the only option? Surely there must be some other mechanisms in place to do this if say I wasn't using ui-router in my app?

Comment: Well, `$stateParams` kind of gave away the fact you're using ui-router. (So I thought: why not use it?) Nevertheless, your point is valid, the thing is that you have multiple requests thus making a really elegant solution difficult. (Been there too) Without ui-router I'd write a flag system that would initialize the code after all flags would be set or you could go beserk and let the requests resolve recursivly as array and init your code when done. (But that  is trying to synchronize asynchoneous code)

Comment: Regarding the reference data: I have used the window.session to store reference data using the URL as key after being requested for the first time. And subsequentely returning a resolved promise with session data.

Comment: @skubski that gives me an idea. Let me try something out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone already mentioned resolve in the $stateProvider is the way to go. 
However what you could also do is this :

```
    'use strict';

    angular.module('YourApp')
        .service('YourService', function ($http) {
            return {
                doSomething: function (id, success, error) {
                    return $http.post(
                        'rest/bla/' + id, {}
                    ).success(function (response) {
                       success(response);
                    }).error(function () {
                        error();
                    });
                },
                doSomethingElse: function (id, success, error) {
                    return $http.post(
                        'rest/bla/' + id, {}
                    ).success(function (response) {
                       success(response);
                    }).error(function () {
                        error();
                    });
                },
                doSomethingDifferent: function (id, success, error) {
                    return $http.post(
                        'rest/bla/' + id, {}
                    ).success(function (response) {
                       success(response);
                    }).error(function () {
                        error();
                    });
                },
            };
        });

        //then in your controller

        angular.module('YourApp')
           .controller('YourController', function(YourService){

           // you add a success and error function for when the data is returned.

            YourService.doSomething(id, function(data){
                $scope.yourData = data;
                YourService.doSomethingElse(id, function(data){
                $scope.somethingElse = data;
                YourService.doSomethingDifferent(id, function(data){
                $scope.somethingDifferent = data;

                // al three have been set so you can place initialization code here 
                }
                }
              }, function(){console.log('something went wrong'));
           });

but what you really should do is this

    $stateProvider.state('myState', {
          url: 'the/url/you/want',
          resolve:{
             yourService: 'yourService' // you are dependency injecting it here,
             yourFetch: function (yourService) {
                 return yourService.yourFetch.$promise;
             },
             yourSecondFetch: function(yourService) {
                return yourService.yourSecondFetch.$promise;
             },
             yourTirthFetch: function(yourService) {
                return yourService.yourTirthFetch.$promise;
             },
             controller: 'YourController'
       })

    // then your controller can just inject the yourFetch and they will be resolved before your controller loads so it will always be fetched prior

    .controller('YourController', function($scope, yourFetch, yourSecondFetch, yourTirthFetch) {
         $scope.yourFetch = yourFetch;
         $scope.secondFetch = yourSecondFetch;
         $scope.tirthFetch = yourTirthFetch;
    });
```

Comment: He is already doing that, by providing a setter function. Synchronize all three requests now!

Comment: @skubski ah you are correct I missed that. well I agree with your comment that he should use resolves in his state

Comment: This is correct, don't get me wrong, but the trick lies in having to create a function that sets initialization code in motion when all three requests are done. You only have one request to handle in this example. Make it work and I'll vote up! =P

Comment: @skubski I updated my first response so he can now do three requests and after that initialization without the worry of the data not being set

Comment: @Arno_Geismar that also sounds good. Let me try something out here.

Comment: @iiminov was my answer helpfull ? if so could you mark it as answer ty

Comment: @Arno_Geismar sorry just trying to get this resolve to work with my factory service because I am not using ``$http``. What I actually use is this ``myApp.factory('GetTags', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/API/Service/GetTagList', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, }, isArray: true,
    });
}]);``

Comment: Sorry nvm I got it going.

Answer (score 1):

I abstracted the idea of @Arno_Geismar into a reusable component/service, but as stated previously this is probably a bad idea of making asychronous code synchronous.

```
self.init = function (array, fx) {
                if (array.length > 0) {
                    //The request for data.
                    if (array[0].data=== null) {
                        $http.get(array[0].link).success(function ($response) {
                            window.session.set(array[0].ref, $response);
                            array[0].data= $response;
                            check(array);
                        }).error(function () {
                            self.init(array, fx);
                        });
                    } else {
                        check(array);
                    }
                } else {
                    exec(fx);
                }
                //Check whether the recursive function can stop.
                function check(array) {
                    //Bypass when all the reference data has been set previously.
                    //All objects are set = exit recursive
                    if (array.every(function (e) {
                            return e.data!== null;
                        })) {
                        exec(fx);
                    } else {
                        self.init(array.slice(1, array.length), fx);
                    }
                }

                //Function to execute the fx, if available.
                function exec(fx) {
                    if (fx !== null) {
                        fx();
                    }
                }
            };
```